# Is a joint image measure of absolutely continuous image measures absolutely continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let $(X,F,\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be measurable functions such that the [image measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) $f(\mu)$ and $g(\mu)$ are absolutely continuous with respect to one-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Now let $h:X^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $h(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$.  Then my question is, is the image measure $h(\mu)$ necessarily absolutely continuous with respect to two-dimensional Lebesgue measure? If not, does anyone know of a counterexample?

Note that this question comes from me trying to better understand joint probability density functions (for non-independent random variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Take $f=g$. Let $\Delta =\{(x,x):x \in \mathbb  R\}$. If $m_2$ denotes two dimensional Lebesgue measure then $m_2(\Delta)=0$. But $\mu ((f,g)^{-1} (\Delta))=1$ so $\mu (f,g)^{-1}$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. $m_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  By the way, is there a standard name for the relationship between $h(\mu)$ with $f(\mu)$ and $g(\mu)$?  It’s not a product measure of the two measures so what is it?

Comment: In probability  theory it is called the joint distribution of $f$ and $g$.